# Depends river stream on river level?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

If we have referral particle in the middle of the river, will it's velocity increase with higher river level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then yes. [This page](http://www.colorado.edu/geography/courses/geog_2043_f01/lab01_2.html), for example, has an image showing a typical velocity profile. The water moves slower near the bottom because of friction.

Comment: Yes, You understand it well, but I think that this friction -> velocity dependency is not do big... in real world, when river level is about 2m higher...

Comment: That may well be true. The name for the part of the flow that's slowed down is the "boundary layer", and in a large river it might be quite a bit smaller than the height of the water. But it will also depend on a lot of things, including the speed of the flow, the roughness of the bottom, and the shape of the river channel. [here](http://www.efm.leeds.ac.uk/CIVE/CIVE1400/Section4/boundary_layer.htm) is some information about boundary layers in rivers. (I haven't read it, so I don't know if it's useful.)